# What is the usage of OTHER_LDFLAGS in podspec?

Tags: ios, swift, plugins, cocoapods

My project has various plugins, and every plugin associate with one podspec file. e.g. I have coreSDK plugin in which we have core functionality for project. In coreSDK podspec we added few dependencies for google, Facebook and twitter.

Currently Im working social integration for all three framework but I observed these three frameworks are not showing added to coreSDK target because of that I am not getting social framework access. One of my friend suggested me to add those frameworks in `OTHER_LDFLAGS` so that they will get added to coreSDK target.

I will do this but before that I want to know what is the purpose of `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in podspec. How it works?

Answer (score 1):

OTHER_LDFLAGS is nothing but Other Linker Flags. It causes the actual pods to be linked into your application.

Answer (score 0):

This flag is used by [xcodebuild](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/xcodebuild/) which uses it when calling [ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) linker to link an app target with a frameworks and indicate in which languages they were written.